# Find the splitting field of $x^4-4x^2+1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: field-theory, splitting-field

I proved that the polynomial $x^4-4x^2+1$ is irreducible over  $\mathbb{Q}$ , so if $a$ is a root of the polynomial, i got:

$x^4-4x^2+1=(x-a)(x+a)(x^2+a^2-4)
$.

I don't know how to prove that the quadratic polynomial is reducible in order to prove that $\mathbb{Q(a)}$ is the splitting field. Thank you all.

Comment: All the roots may be computed easily. First, compute the roots of $X^2-4X+1$.

Comment: Why do i have to compute the roots of this polynomial?

Comment: This polynomial is in "quadratic form." Substitute $y$ for $x^2$, and you'll obtain a quadratic (the one @GreginGre mentioned). If you know the roots of that polynomial, then the roots of the desired polynomial are the square roots of each of those roots.

Comment: @PietroSileci you can make $a$ explicit.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i didn't think about it.

Comment: I think the comments above are misleading. People are indicating that you should write the four roots as $\pm\sqrt{2\pm\sqrt 3}$, but this is not really useful in showing that one root generates all others. The crucial observation is that the pairs of roots are inverses of each other and this can be derived directly from $a^4 - 4a^2 + 1$ without knowing anything about $2\pm\sqrt 3$ etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that $\frac 1 a(=4a - a^3)$ is also a root of the polynomial.

Thus it suffices to check that $x^2 + a^2 - 4 = (x - \frac 1 a)(x + \frac 1 a)$, which is easy.

Answer (score 0):

If $a$ is a root of $f(x)=x^4-4x^2+1$, then $f(1/a)=\frac{1}{a^4}-\frac{4}{a^2}+1=\frac{1}{a^4}(1-4a^2+a^4)=\frac{f(a)}{a^4}=0$, as $a$ is a root.  So, your roots are $\pm a$ and $\pm\frac{1}{a}$.   Thus your splitting field is $\mathbb{Q}(a)$.
Based on GreginGre's comment, we can explicitly find $a$ as $a=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}$.

Answer (score 0):

You can also complete the square with varying the middle term,
$$
0=x^4−4x^2+1=(x^2−1)^2−2x^2=(x^2+1)^2−6x^2
$$
and use the binomial identities to factorize further.
These real factorizations then allow a direct computation of the roots via the quadratic solution formula or a standard quadratic completion.

**first variant**
$$0=x^2\pm\sqrt2x-1=(x\pm\sqrt{1/2})^2-3/2$$

**second variant**
$$
0=x^2\pm\sqrt6+1=(x\pm\sqrt{3/2})^2-\frac12
$$

Both ways lead to the same root set $\pm\sqrt{1/2}\pm\sqrt{3/2} \in\Bbb Q[\sqrt2,\sqrt3]$.